# Android Window title showing after requested not to show

Tags: android, android-activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent i = new Intent(this, BaseActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

and my next activity:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);
    }
```

I still see blue bar with application name at top.
I tried changing my application manifest to use a no-title theme and the program crashed because the activities inherit from `AppCompatActivity`.

How do I inherit from `AppCompatActivity` and get rid of the application title name up top?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's the actionbar, you can use the theme *Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar* or *Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar* or a theme which descents from them.

To make disappear is the action bar also this should work:

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Comment: I've tried all of that, it's still there. Adding picture to my post

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

If you don't want the action bar in your `activity` then,

Create a style

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

and apply this style for the `activity` in `Manifest` for which you don't need action bar,

```
<activity android:name=".BaseActivity"
          android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your onCreate() method.

```
//Remove title bar
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

//Remove notification bar
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

//set content view AFTER ABOVE sequence (to avoid crash)
this.setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_name_here);
```

this refers to the Activity

**OR**

You can modify your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```

You can use this for each activity in your project.

**OR**

also change from style.xml

```
<style name="generalnotitle" parent="general">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I tried the first solution - no effect.. I want to keep my theme the same, how can I do this in code?